# Delaying display of the new content until layout is complete

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dom

When dynamically changing content within a div is there a way of delaying the display of the new content until all layout is complete?

I am using javascript and ajax to update the contents of a div and when I insert the html returned by the ajax script it appears to doing the layout of the new content after the elements are visible, spilling outside of the target div

While this happens quickly and the end result is exactly as I desire it to be it does create an unpleasant 'flickering' that I would like to avoid

javascript

```
      $requestURL = 'Scripts/getCategoryItems.php?Category='+$category+'&PageLength='+$pageLength+'&Page='+$page ;  
  AjaxRequest.open('GET',$requestURL,true);
    AjaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
      { if(AjaxRequest.readyState == 4)
        { 
          if (AjaxRequest.responseText !== 'false') 
          { TargetContainer.style.display = "none";
            TargetContainer.innerHTML=AjaxRequest.responseText;
            TargetContainer.style.display = "block";
          } else { alert(AjaxRequest.responseText); } ;
          document.body.className = '';
        }
      };
  document.body.className = 'waiting';
  AjaxRequest.send();
```

Html:

```
<div id="Content" style="float:left; width:820px; height:550px; max-height:550px; color:#E0E0E0;  padding-top:30px; overflow:hidden;"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could run your code within the document ready so that the document is fully loaded before you start making your ajax call.

*EDIT*: Or if you're not using jQuery then the window.onload event.

Comment: ajax call is made in response to user interaction so the document is fully loaded

Comment: Ok, if that's the case then seeing the code that is being used in to load the part of the document that is flickering would be helpful. If, for example, you are using something like jQuery's fadein there is a callback on that your could use. I'm not saying you are using fadein but the point I'm making is the code you are wanting to run synchronously before your ajax is relevant to helping you find a solution.

Comment: using just straight javascript, html and php. There is no code running prior to the ajax call, the page is static displaying a series of images. When user selects a different category the ajax call is made and the innerhtml of the display div is replaced with the html of a new series of images